# Primefaces p:menuitem with p:confirm not supported

Tags: primefaces, confirm

I'm trying to call a confirmation dialog on a `p:menuitem`:

```
<p:menuitem value="#{text['button.archive']}"  actionListener="#{tasksbacking.archive}" icon="ui-icon-locked">                            
    <p:confirm header="#{text['button.archive.confirm.header']}" 
               message="#{text['button.archive.confirm.message']}"
               icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:menuitem>
```

but according to the documentation in Primefaces 5:

> At the moment p:confirm is supported by p:commandButton and p:commandLink

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found better workaround [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33874).

In two words - include `commandlink` into `menuitem` like this:

```
....
<p:menuitem>
    <p:commandLink>
        <p:confirm>
        </p:confirm>
    </p:commandLink>
</p:menuitem>
....
```

And you can use global confirmation with this setup. It tested with PF 5.1. Also, it looks like soon it will be implemented in [PrimeFaces](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7954).

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this question today. After a bit of try and error, and respecting the information out of the already posted links in the comments, if tried to do the following, and unexpectedly, this works for me. I'm on PF 5.3

```
<p:menuitem value="Löschen"
    actionListener="#{importerDefinitionView.deleteSelectedFile()}"
    update="messages">
    <p:confirm header="Datei Löschen"
        message="Soll die Datei wirklich gelöscht werden?"
        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:menuitem>
```

The relating confirm-dialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```